# neo4j NOT IN query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple query

```
MATCH p=(a:User)-[r:VISITS]->(end:Page)
WHERE r.rating<2 AND t.rating>5
RETURN EXTRACT (n IN nodes(p)|n.page_id) ,count(p)
ORDER BY count(p) DESC;
```

This works fine. However, each `end` node is assigned a property `page_id`. I have an external python script that generates a list of page_id that are whitelisted and should be ignored. For example page_id_white=[1,4,5,6] should be ignored and the code should return only paths where `end.page_id` is not in `page_id_white`. I have tried a simple NOT IN page_id_white statement, but it didn't work. Can someone help me out on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't do `NOT IN`. Needs to be `WHERE NOT thing IN coll`.

```
MATCH p=(a:User)-[r:VISITS]->(end:Page)
WHERE NOT end.page_id IN {page_id_white}
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(p) | n.page_id), COUNT(p)
ORDER BY COUNT(p) DESC;
```

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong, but after I let my code run (it's a huge database), I woke up to this message: `py2neo.neo4j.ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named page_id_white` I can start a new question, let me know if I need to do that.

Comment: `{page_id_white}` is a parameter. You can pass parameters easily with py2neo. Otherwise, you can specifically insert a collection like `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Yes, it works when I insert a collection. I will have a look on how to pass a parameter. Thanks!

Comment: If you're on py2neo 2.0, it would just be `graph.cypher.execute(query, dict(page_id_white = [1,2,3]))`